# gulp minifies already minified file

Tags: javascript, gulp

I try to minify separate .js-files with gulp. Like:

```
file_one.js --> file_one.min.js
file_two.js --> file_two.min.js
```

It works the first time I execute gulp. But if I run it a second time it looks like this:

```
file_one.js 
file_one.min.js
file_one.min.min.js
file_two.js
file_two.min.js
file_two.min.min.js
```

And it repeats that pattern every timme i execute gulp. How can I stop it from minify already minified js.

I use the following code:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src('dest/*js')
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is happening because you are saving the minified files in the same directory of your non minified files. The first part of your stream (`gulp.src`) reads all files inside your `dest` folder. Since you are saving your minified files to the very same folder, it is minifying them again on the second time it is run. the You have some options:

1. Change the output folder to something else (for instance `gulp.dest('build')`)
2. Change `gulp.src` to match only the non-minified files

Comment: I think the OP was asking for clarification on how to do your point 2. i.e. "match the non-minified files"

Comment: @RickDavies just read the comments. This solution worked for him. No need to downvote.

Comment: @MarlonBernardes I did read the comments and although the OP accepted your answer to his very real problem I don't believe it answered the intent of his original question, per my comment above. This is an open forum and other people searching for an answer to his question (viz. minifying files in the same directory) might be unsatisfied by yours. I was and downvoted it, also upvoting the answer by Patrik Oldsberg. That's my prerogative.

Answer (score 26):

You can put the minified files in a different directory, or you can exclude them in the `gulp.src`like this:

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return gulp.src(['dest/*.js', '!dest/*.min.js'])
        .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dest'));
});
```

Comment: Had the to be excluded minified files in a separate array first: `gulp.src(['css/*.css'], ['!css/*.min.css'])`, not like this in one set of `[]` . This worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are having problem with duplicate so you need to delete the destination file first to re-run the file. See Example:

```
//clean
gulp.task('clean', function(){
    return del(['dist']);
});

    //Default task
    gulp.task('default',['clean'], function(){
        gulp.start('usemin','imagemin','copy','views');
    });
```